# Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) protocols other than GATT

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

**Are there any other methods or protocols other than GATT which can be used under BLE (single mode chips) which are better suited to higher-throughput tasks?**

From what I understand the answer to my question is no, but I would like some validation and clarification.

---

I would like to implement services which involve more than simply manipulating (short) characteristics via BLE. Such services might include file transfer, audio streaming, and basically services which are standard in previous versions of bluetooth.

A convenient solution would be to use the File Transfer Profile (over GOEP) or similar for file transfer. For audio, A2DP seems suitable. However, these do not seem to be possible using BLE.

After reading the core spec v4 from bluetooth.org (specifically Vol. 3), it seems like the only applicable protocol which I can use and adapt (via profiles) for such purposes is GATT, which seems very awkward to use.

Also, according to [Overview and Evaluation of Bluetooth Low Energy: An Emerging Low-Power Wireless Technology](http://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/12/9/11734), it seems like the effective throughput is low:

> Whereas the physical layer data rate is 1 Mbps, the maximum application layer throughput 
>   is equal to 236.7 kbps.

However (when measuring real-world performance using TI CC254x via GATT):

> ... In the described conditions, the maximum application layer throughput we have measured is 58.48 kbps. This 
>   low result can be explained by the following two facts: (i) whereas, in theory, up to eleven such 
>   notifications can be transmitted within a connection event of 7.5 ms, only four notifications are 
>   allowed per connection event, as aforementioned; and (ii) we have observed that less than four 
>   notifications are actually transmitted in most connection events during the experiment (however, the 
>   same phenomenon occurs less frequently for connection intervals greater than 7.5 ms). These 
>   observations show that high throughput has not been a primary goal in the design of the BLE 
>   implementation used in the evaluation.

I realize the above text is specific to the implementation on the TI chip, but such limitations could also apply to other implementations above GATT as well.

Comment: http://www.google.com/patents/US20130045684 The described embodiments include a system for communicating between electronic devices. During operation, a receiving electronic device receives a data channel protocol data unit (PDU) in a link layer of a Bluetooth Low Energy (BTLE) protocol stack.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are writing your own profiles, then you can do whatever you want by opening an L2CAP channel and sending data in any format, without implementing GATT.  L2CAP would let you get the max throughput, and be suitable for streaming data as opposed to reading characteristics.

Comment: True, except that most APIs today don't give you access to L2CAP because the only channels officially sanctioned are SMP and ATT

Comment: True, but it's possible.  On BlueZ/Linux, you can send arbitrary HCI commands to BT devices, so you have full control.  The amount of work involved is not practical for most applications though.

Comment: Of course, on BlueZ or other platforms where you have HCI-level and L2CAP-level access it is possible, but those are in the minority. Most of the APIs out there give you GAP/GATT level access and that's all you can do. Nordic Semiconductor's nRF51 series does give you L2CAP-level APIs so that should be possible.

Comment: Seems like L2CAP channels can indeed provide the type of data transfer needed, while circumventing implementation issues with GATT such as I've described in the question.
It seems like this would be possible with a little hacking for the TI CC254x platform which I'm using, since they provide full source code for their entire BLE stack once you purchase the license.

Comment: @scooz which license should I purchase in order to get the source for the stack. I thought it's proprietary.

Comment: Before BT core spec 4.1 is adopted, you cannot transfer non-GATT data through L2CAP over BLE. In BT core spec 4.1, the connection-oriented L2CAP connection is introduced to transfer data through some dedicated L2CAP channels (e.g. IPv6 packets).

Answer (score 4):

Please see what we have been doing for a long time: IPv6 over BTLE, which is still one IETF draft in the 6LoWPAN WG, and the proposal has been approved in Bleutooth SIG. Here is the news in BLuetooth Technical Updates: 19 Feb, 2013.

> IPv6 Over Low Energy New Work Proposal Approved
>
> The IPv6 Over LE New Work Proposal (NWP) submitted by Bluetooth SIG
>   members is approved. This NWP proposes that permitting IPv6 over the
>   Low Energy transport will enable new use cases (in home and industrial
>   automation as well as smart metering) not covered by GATT profiles.
>   The proposed work meets the requirements defined by the Internet
>   Engineering Task Force (IETF) as well as complements the work done in
>   the IP for Smart Objects (IPSO) alliance.   The Internet Working Group
>   will develop a Functional Requirements Document (FRD) based on the
>   approved NWP. If you are an Adopter member and want to participate in
>   the FRD development process, please contact the Internet Working Group
>   Chair.

Answer (score 2):

There is stuff coming up, if you're a member of the SIG look up the Tech Specs section of bluetooth.org

Comment: I've looked at the enhancements (https://www.bluetooth.org/Technical/Specifications/enhancements.htm), and didn't find any proposal for LE relevant to this situation. Can you be more specific?

Comment: L2CAP connection oriented channels

Comment: At the latest BT4.1 spec, similar to L2CAP_PSM for classic Bluetooth, the "LE_PSM" is adde to handle variable high-layer protocols over different channels, which is very helpful to implement the L2CAP CoC (a.k.a Connection Oriented Channels) functions over LE.