# bluetooth low energy stack for linux

Tags: bluetooth, linux-device-driver, bluetooth-lowenergy

How is bluetooth low energy implemented at a device driver level in linux?

Is there a new bluetooth stack code for every new bluetooth version ?

Answer (score 3):

[Bluez](http://www.bluez.org/) is the stack for Linux Bluetooth.  New version of Bluetooth have resulted in changes in the code, but it's not a complete rewrite or anything drastic like that.  Newer versions of Bluetooth are typically extensions of the existing protocol with the exception of Low Energy.  Low Energy is completely supported at the kernel level in Linux, but there aren't a lot of convenience libraries for higher level interaction with LE.

Due to the incompleteness of Bluez with LE I've had to interact with the kernel code directly in order to implement functionality with LE.  Also, I had to use older kernels that aren't supported by Bluez 5.x and had to use Bluez 4.x.

Answer (score 1):

Already Tim and jhonnash have provided comprehensive information to your question. However, I would like to add one more information from Android Mobile point of view.

New version of Android uses Bluedroid as Bluetooth stack. This is quite different from Bluez.

Bluez has functionality distributed both in user space and kernel space. All the protocols like RFCOMM, HCI and L2CAP are implemented at kernel level and Profiles are implemented at User space. As Tim mentioned, to support Low energy, Bluez has to provide support at kernel level as well as at user space. This some times get difficult to track and understand. Any new changes **may** require modification in kernel as well as in user space code.

On the other hand, Bluedroid has some advantage over Bluez. Bluedroid has implemented its complete functionality at user space. Due to which any new functionality only needs to be added at user level code. No dependency on Kernel code.

Also, to answer your question of *"Is there a new bluetooth stack code for every new bluetooth version ?"*  No complete rewrite is required for new version of Bluetooth as Bluetooth new versions are **backward compatible**, so only those portion of codes are added to the already existing stack which is new.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

As your question is not completly clear that's why I also try to give all the possible protocols available to access bluetooth low enery stack for linux.

In [UHID Driver](http://dvdhrm.wordpress.com/2012/07/16/uhid-user-space-hid-io-drivers/) "HoG (HID over GATT/Bluetooth-Low-Energy): GATT is a Bluetooth protocol implemented in user-space. When user-space opens an LE (low-energy) connection to a Bluetooth device, the device can advertise HID capabilities via GATT."
As [GATT](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/linux/bluetooth/bluez/attrib/gatt-service.c) service is properly defined in this link.
      There can be other protocols than GATT to access the [Low-energy devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360607/bluetooth-low-energy-ble-protocols-other-than-gatt). HID Over GATT implementation is done in this manner.